# Custom element with shadow not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to make a custom element with a shadow, but when I add a shadow, the content of the element doesn't render. Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
 constructor (){
  super();
  var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  var content = document.createElement("DIV");
  content.innerText = "hello world";
  shadow.appendChild(content);
 }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomElement);
```

HTML:

```html
<custom-element>blah blah blah</custom-element>
```

But all it renders is the text "hello world"

Comment: https://codepen.io/Utsav91/pen/eXxmdZ?&editable=true

On codepen it works, I have removed my answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal behaviour of a Shadow DOM : the Shadow DOM content masks the original content (called the Light DOM).

If you want to reveal the Light DOM content, use [`<slot>`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#slots) in the Shadow DOM.

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
 constructor (){
  super();
  var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  var content = document.createElement("DIV");
  content.innerHTML = "hello world: <br> <slot></slot>";
  shadow.appendChild(content);
 }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomElement);
```

```html
<custom-element>blah blah blah</custom-element>
```